# Getting OnClick value from dynamically generated button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink

I am trying to get the onClick value from hyperlink that is generated by a javascript file on run time.

I am able to get the value when i click on it using JQuery as i can get JQuery to focus on the hyperlink that is being used.

On run time however this is a different story, our problem is also that link(anchor) doesn't have an ID so i can't just pick it up.

I can not edit the javascript file as its a vendor file. Any get would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: `$('parent element in dom').on('click', 'a[href]', ...)`, what do you mean "focus" on the link being used? **Edit**: clarified selector.

Comment: try to find other things about that button; if you don't have the id, maybe you do have the parent id. maybe the button has a unique classname, or it is always the first of its class in the DOM.

Comment: unfortunately no, i has no name or id, which makes it hard. is there a way to search for the content of a link to get it maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use event delegation ([jQuery](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), [vanilla JavaScript](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate)) to add your event listeners to the element which contains the generated elements.

Here's a contrived example:

```
// presumably the elements live in some distinct container
$('.vendor-div').on('click', 'a', function () {
    console.log('hullo!');
});

setTimeout(function () {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.setAttribute('href', '#');
    a.textContent = "click me!";
    $('.vendor-div').append(a);
}, 1000);
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qmL47r41/)

Comment: sorry i am not following. can you please elaborate?

Comment: If the dynamically generated elements are appended to a particular wrapper element, you can attach use event delegation to attach a listener to that. If that's not the case, and they're being appended throughout the page, you could use event delegation `body` and filter clicks (using the link's contents or whatever) in the body of the handler. If it's the latter, I can update my answer accordingly.